# Single versus split power supplies for op amps

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

Application is small signal (low mV).
What are the tradeoffs between using a dual supply as opposed to single supply and virtual ground? Apart from maybe the cost of supplying a DC-DC converter to a battery based system.

Comment: split power supply or virtual ground are the same thing, usually to choose between the two you need infos on how you want the input and the output. i.e., if you can AC couple the input then virtual ground is good, but maybe the output must be dc coupled and that would be a mess with virtual ground... add some insights.

Comment: The difference is that the split PSU comes from a DC-DC converter whose GND is connected to the GND of the battery/external_psu. Whereas the virtual ground would be from a voltage reference or divider and unity gain opamp

Comment: In my application input can be AC but the output needs to be a DC referenced level (being fed into an ADC, 0-2V5)

Comment: I'm looking to simplify an existing circuit, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my application input can be AC but the output needs to be a DC
>   referenced level (being fed into an ADC, 0-2V5)

If your application is AC then you can couple the signal via a capacitor to a 1.25V reference voltage provided by resistors - this sets the average voltage at 1.25 volts i.e. half the ADC range. This strikes me as the easiest way to deal with this application.

If your AC signal is differential then you might consider using an instrumentation amplifer but this may likely have to operate from split supplies.

Answer (score 0):

"*What are the tradeoffs between using a dual supply as opposed to single supply and virtual ground?*"

There are two important aspects connected with such a trade-off:

1.) AC applications for single supply configurations always are connected with a lower cut-off frequency (high-pass effect due to the coupling capacitor).

2.) You must ensure unity dc gain (requires an additional capacitor in the feedback path for non-inv. operation).